# Using same form as local and remote both in rails for filtering purposes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

**Scenario:**

I have a form that does some filtering. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume I have a form that has three input options:

```
<%= form_tag(some_path,method: :get) do %>
     #..checkboxes for option 1
     #..radiobuttons for option 2
     #..checkboxes for option 3
     <%= submit_tag "submit" %>
<% end %>
<p>You have a total of: COUNT results.</p>
```

**Required Output:**

What I want is the functionality when a user clicks on any checkbox or radio button, (essentially a change in any input field), by ajax request should be generated to a path that returns a COUNT of total results, and I will update the COUNT inside p tag with that returned count number.

And when the user clicks on submit button, the default GET request should be generated.

Comment: "when a user clicks on any checkbox or radio button" - it's not what remote form does. You need a jquery function with AJAX request

Comment: You'll need to write some JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this script for ajax request, and it is working perfectly fine.

```
<script>
$(".option").change(function(){
    var type = $("input[name='type[]']:checked").map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/gre",
        type: "put",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {custom: 'true',type: type},
        success: function (response) {
          var count = response["count"];
          $('#count').html('Your session will have a total of '+ count + ' questions.');
        }
    });
});
```